# What is the most efficient way of checking if value exists in a range of start and end positions in Python?

Tags: python, performance, python-3.7, memory-efficient

Lets say I have a text file that has start and end positions like this:

```
Start End
  1     5
 11    14
 15    19
 23    30
```

I want to check if a given set of values exists in between and including those positions, e.g. 4,14,20  would return TRUE,TRUE,FALSE.

What would be the most efficient way of doing so?

Idea 1) I could generate each possible number into a list and check if value is in list - pseudo code would look like this:

```
list = []
values = [4,14,20]
for line in file:
    for position in range(int(line.split()[0]),int(line.split()[1])+1):
        list.append(position) #Populate list with every viable position

for value in values:
    if value in list:
        print("TRUE")
    else:
        print("FALSE")
```

Idea 2) Instead of saving each possible position into the list, save only the start and end but then iterate through each range when checking:

```
list = []
for line in file:
    list.append(line) #Save only start and end into list

for value in values:
    for start_end in list:
        for position in range(int(start_end.split()[0]),int(start_end.split()[1])+1):
            if value == position:
                print("TRUE")
```

If my file is very large I suspect idea 1 would take up a lot of memory, but on the other hand would idea 2 take much longer to run as it has to iterate through so much more?

Or is there some completely different way that is better?
Many thanks!

Comment: don't make the `range` into a list, **just use the `range` object**. That's what they are for.

Comment: are you sure the example output you provided is correct? should it not be True, False, False? Is the check to be made "per line" or is it some other kind of test?

Answer (score 4):

**Verifying a value is in a set of ranges**

There's no need to generate and iterate through lists. My suspicion is that it would be more efficient to simply use comparison operators.

However, if you want to confirm which is the most efficient approach, use [profiling tools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html#instant-user-s-manual).

Here's an example of profiling a few approaches to finding out if a value is within a set of ranges to verify which approach is most efficient.

```
import cProfile

# Input data.
ranges = [[1, 5], [11, 14], [15, 19], [23, 30]]
values = [4, 14, 40]

# An implementation using a comparison operator (i.e. "<=").
def is_in_range_comparison_operator(v):
    for r in ranges:
        if r[0] <= v <= r[1]:
            return True
    return False

# An implementation using a range object.
def is_in_range_range_object(v):
    for r in ranges:
        if v in range(r[0], r[1]+1):
            return True
    return False

# An implementation using precomputed range objects.
range_objects = [range(r[0], r[1]+1) for r in ranges]
def is_in_range_precomputed_range_objects(v):
    for r in range_objects:
        if v in r:
            return True
    return False

# A list of the implementations, to make looping through them easier.
implementations = [
        is_in_range_comparison_operator,
        is_in_range_range_object,
        is_in_range_precomputed_range_objects,
        ]

# A function to execute an implementation and print output.
def is_in_range(is_in_range_func):
    print("Using {}:".format(is_in_range_func.func_name))
    for v in values:
        if is_in_range_func(v):
            print ("True")
        else:
            print ("False")
    print

# Run each implementation, printing out the results.
for f in implementations:
    is_in_range(f)

# A function for executing a implementation repeatedly, for profiling purposes.
def test_is_in_range(is_in_range_func, num_iterations):
    for _ in range(num_iterations):
        for v in values:
            if is_in_range_func(v):
               pass

# Profile each implementation by running it num_iterations times.
num_iterations = 100000
for f in implementations:
    command = "test_is_in_range({}, {})".format(
            f.func_name, num_iterations)
    print("Profiling the following command: {}".format(command))
    cProfile.run(command)
```

And here's the output of executing the script:

```
$ python in_range.py
Using is_in_range_comparison_operator:
True
True
False

Using is_in_range_range_object:
True
True
False

Using is_in_range_precomputed_range_objects:
True
True
False

Profiling the following command: test_is_in_range(is_in_range_comparison_operator, 100000)
         300004 function calls in 0.388 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.388    0.388 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    0.172    0.172    0.388    0.388 in_range.py:51(test_is_in_range)
   300000    0.212    0.000    0.212    0.000 in_range.py:8(is_in_range_comparison_operator)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
        1    0.004    0.004    0.004    0.004 {range}


Profiling the following command: test_is_in_range(is_in_range_range_object, 100000)
         1000004 function calls in 1.209 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    1.209    1.209 <string>:1(<module>)
   300000    0.639    0.000    1.033    0.000 in_range.py:15(is_in_range_range_object)
        1    0.174    0.174    1.209    1.209 in_range.py:51(test_is_in_range)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
   700001    0.396    0.000    0.396    0.000 {range}


Profiling the following command: test_is_in_range(is_in_range_precomputed_range_objects, 100000)
         300004 function calls in 0.391 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.391    0.391 <string>:1(<module>)
   300000    0.220    0.000    0.220    0.000 in_range.py:23(is_in_range_precomputed_range_objects)
        1    0.171    0.171    0.391    0.391 in_range.py:51(test_is_in_range)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
        1    0.001    0.001    0.001    0.001 {range}
```

Some conclusions from the profiling results:

- Using comparison operators is more efficient than repeatedly instantiating range objects.
- Using precomputed range objects is on par with using comparison operators.

However, if you have a huge numbers of ranges to handle, it will probably end up being more efficient to forego using range objects. Which leads to...

---

**Efficiently handling an arbitrarily large set of ranges**

If your input set of ranges is sufficiently large that you're worried about memory exhaustion, here's an approach that handles each range one at a time, testing all values against that range.

Notes:

- The approach is processing each range one at a time, testing all values against it. This allows for processing an arbitrary number of ranges without having to ingest all of them up front.
- This doesn't account for an arbitrary number of values to search for.
- There are some optimizations based on both the input ranges and values being sorted. If sorted input cannot be relied upon, the optimizations can be modified or removed accordingly.

```
ranges = [[4, 5], [11, 14], [15, 19], [23, 30]]
values = [4, 14, 20]

# Create a dictionary to keep track whether or not each value falls within
# a range, with a default value of False.
is_value_in_range = {}

def init_results():
    global is_value_in_range
    is_value_in_range = {v: False for v in values}

def print_values_and_results():
    for v in values:
        print("{}: {}".format(v, is_value_in_range[v]))

def check_for_values_in_range(r, values_index):
    for i, v in enumerate(values[values_index:]):

        # If the value is greater than the upper end of the range, move on
        # to the next range.
        if v > r[1]:
            return (values_index + i, True)

        # If the value is less than the lower end and we're on the last
        # value, stop altogether.
        if v < r[0] and values_index == len(values) - 1:
            return (0, False)

        if r[0] <= v <= r[1]:
            is_value_in_range[v] = True

    return (values_index, True)

def check_for_values_in_ranges(verbose=False):
    init_results()
    if verbose:
        print("Initial results:")
        print_values_and_results()
        print
    i = 0
    for r in ranges:
        i, continue_searching = check_for_values_in_range(r, i)
        if verbose:
            print("After checking range: {}".format(r))
            print_values_and_results()
            print
        if not continue_searching:
            break

    print("Final results:")
    print_values_and_results()
    print

print("*** Check ranges for values (non-verbose) ***")
check_for_values_in_ranges()

print("*** Check ranges for values (verbose) ***")
check_for_values_in_ranges(True)
```

Output of the script:

```
$ python large_input.py
*** Check ranges for values (non-verbose) ***
Final results:
4: True
14: True
20: False

*** Check ranges for values (verbose) ***
Initial results:
4: False
14: False
20: False

After checking range: [4, 5]
4: True
14: False
20: False

After checking range: [11, 14]
4: True
14: True
20: False

After checking range: [15, 19]
4: True
14: True
20: False

After checking range: [23, 30]
4: True
14: True
20: False

Final results:
4: True
14: True
20: False
```

Comment: Profiling is a good idea. But you go vertically, checking each value against each range (i.e. each line in the file is loaded in memory, but the file may be large). 2. I think the operator does not depend of the iteration on the ranges. Bring the iteration on the ranges out of it, into the main loop and let the operator do its job on one range at a time

Comment: If the primary concern of the question is about the mechanics of processing a large file, that can be explored as well. 

However, in both approaches presented in the question, the full file contents are being ingested as the first step. The focus of my answer was to optimize the range checking logic.

Comment: The OP clearly asks for the most efficient way to solve the problem. The problem specifies range values in a file and it entails large files. I think your approach to solve the problme is good and professional. Just go by range instead of by value, since I/O outweighs any processing gain and large data sets impact the problem (they often are the problem)

Comment: Note: going by line (i.e. by range) allows you to compute `range()` once only and use it against all values. That speeds things up

Comment: That's a good point. Now I have to decide which aspect to focus on... revisiting the approach already discussed or exploring approaches to handling a large input set of ranges.

Comment: @Pynchia Thanks for the push, exploring that problem space was fun.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I misunderstood something, but why don't try something like this? It's easier and works.

```
limits = {"a":[1,5],"b":[11,14],"c":[15,19],"d":[23,30]}
values = [3,14,20]
for var in limits:
    for a in values:
        if a in range(limits[var][0],limits[var][1]+1):
            print ("TRUE")
        else:
            print ("FALSE")
```

output:

> TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, / FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, / FALSE, FALSE, FALSE / FALSE, FALSE, FALSE

Comment: can you please use the OP's input values and check you get the correct output? Thanks

Comment: Also, please make the code work against the input file as it is described

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to read from a large file one line at a time after creating a link to it using `open`. For a short example:

```
values = [4, 14, 20]
with open("some_file.txt", "r") as f:
    for test_val in values:
        min_val, max_val = f.readline().split()
        print(test_val >= int(min_val) and test_val <= int(max_val))
```

This would print out:

```
True
True
False
```

Open creates an iterator that stores the last accessed part of the file being linked to. In this example, `readline` uses that iterator as a sort of "data bookmark". On the first call `readline` pulls from the start of the file until a line break is found and then sets the bookmark after that line break. Each subsequent call of `readline` after the first picks up from where the bookmark was last placed until the next line break that is found. Once the next found line break is found, the bookmark is moved there.

Comment: You do not need a cathedral to pray. `open` returns an iterator already, no need to yield again just to extract the range limits. It is tidier yes, but here the problem is the most efficient way to perform the task. It entails reading from the file AND checking if the values fall in each range. Please do go ahead and add the second half

Comment: Ah, good point. This is what I get for thinking about this backward starting with the `yield` statement instead of starting from `open`. I will amend my answer.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is simple and succint, but it allows the processing of large files and does not need any indexing/enumeration:

```
vals = (4,14,20)
with open('rangefile.txt') as f:
    next(f)  # skip header
    for line in f:
        start, end = map(int, line.split())
        matches = [start <= v <= end for v in vals]
        print(matches)
```

which, with an input file of

```
Start End
  1     5
 11    14
 15    19
 23    30
```

it produces

```
[True, False, False]
[False, True, False]
[False, False, False]
[False, False, False]
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you also don't need **range**

You have to just check `<` and `>`:

```
listRange=[[ 1     ,5],[ 11 ,   14],[ 15  ,  19],[ 23  ,  30]]
value =[4,14,20]
for i , t in enumerate(value,start=0): 
  if t>=listRange[i][0] and t<=listRange[i][1]:
    print ('TRUE')
  else:
    print ('FALSE')
```

Comment: 1. Indexing is absolutely unnecessary. 2. please make the code work against the input file as it is described

Comment: @Pynchia _Indexing is absolutely unnecessary_ oh I miss that

Comment: And your code assumes the lines are all in memory, which is wrong for a number of reasons. The OP says the file may be very large, so your approach is wrong

Comment: @Pynchia _please make the code work against the input file as it is described_ As I thought here we are may provide brief  Idea to solve the problem not the whole  solution

Comment: It's not about the whole solution. It's about the fact that files have their pros and cons. Especially the large ones

Answer (score -1):

Optimizing your "idea 2":

- parse the input only once; by parsing I mean to split lines and convert strings to integers
- use simple and fast comparison `start <= value <= end`, no `range` objects necessary
- short-circuit the evaluation, i.e. stop after first matching interval is found
- and also: avoid `list` as a variable name

The result part1:

```
selist = []
with open(filename) as file:
    for line in file:
        n1, n2 = line.split()
        selist.append((int(n1), int(n2))) #Save only start and end into list
```

and part2:

```
for value in values:
    result = any(start <= value <= end for start, end in selist)
    print(result)   # True or False
```

Further optimization is possible if ranges are not overlapping and there are lots of them. Then you could sort them and use bisection.

Comment: Feel free to downote, if you see something wrong, not helpful, or misleading in my answer, but please leave a comment.

Answer (score -2):

An example using DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Start': [1, 11, 15, 23], 'End': [5, 14, 19, 30]})
your_list = [4, 14, 20]

for x in your_list:
    print([item[0] <= x <= item[1] for item in df.itertuples(index=False)])
> [True, False, False, False]
> [False, True, False, False]
> [False, False, False, False]
```

Comment: why involve pandas here at all if you aren't going to take advantage of it?

Comment: Why I received -1?